# JavaFX - how to wait for selection?

Tags: java, select, javafx, tableview, wait

I'm programing a tableview. And after the user presses a button, the program should wait until he has selected two columns and then continue...

How can I wait for the two selects?

**Pseudocode:**

```
button(){
  if(selected2column != true){
     wait
  }
else{
  do stuff..
  }
}
```

When two columns are selected, he should skip the *if*
[image]

My problem is the wait. How can I wait for the two selects?
And I don't want to use multithreads if there is any other possibility...

Comment: Could you post an image for this!

Comment: i updated the question

Comment: I don't understand why you need to wait. Make a field buttonPressed an if selected2column and buttonPressed are true do stuff.

Comment: and if they are false i have to wait, until they get true